# storing date in sql database from android activity

Tags: android, mysql, datepicker

i am using this method to set date in a textview(mDateDisplay) using datepickerin android (the datepicker has the format "jan-09-2001")

```
private void updateDisplay() {
        this.mDateDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                    .append(mDay).append("-")
                    .append(mYear).append(" "));}
```

Now I have converted the content of textview(mDateDisplay) to store it in mysql database
    String DateA= mDateDisplay.getText().toString();

```
// Building Parameters
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("AvlDate",DateA));


and in the php file:
$dd=$_POST['AvlDate'];
$AvlDate =date('y-m-d',strtotime($dd);
```

but this always stores 1970-01-01 in the database..
how do I store the correct result

Answer (score 0):

use

```
private void updateDisplay() {
    this.mDateDisplay.setText(
        new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(mYear).append("-")
                .append(mMonth+1).append("-")
                .append(mDay).append(" "));}
```

you are setting date in `m-d-y` but reading in `y-m-d`